# Firebase and Google Analytics Frameworks are duplicated in iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics, duplicate-symbol

I upgraded the Firebase version to 3.2 in my swift project.
I used the guide in firebase.google.com.
I tried to run app but following issues are occurred in build project.
I think this issue is appeared owing to the migration of the Google and Firebase in the latest firebase version.
How can I fix this issue?

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACPResultData in: /Volumes/MacData/Develop/Project/MyWork/iSpiMi/iSpiMi_iOS_New /Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o) /Volumes/MacData/Develop/Project/MyWork/iSpiMi/iSpiMi_iOS_New /Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_b3f2c8068b01605ef7f3a1753d3917b7.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ACPResultData in: /Volumes/MacData/Develop/Project/MyWork/iSpiMi/iSpiMi_iOS_New /Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(GmpMeasurement.pb.o) /Volumes/MacData/Develop/Project/MyWork/iSpiMi/iSpiMi_iOS_New /Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(GmpMeasurement.pb_b3f2c8068b01605ef7f3a1753d3917b7.o) ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)